# Bash: pattern matching

Tags: grep

I want a terminal command which will find patterns in a text document and outputs them.
The pattern is like `prefix[anything]sufix`, where [anything] can be any text.
I know `grep` command but don't know how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-E` regexp switch. `.*` matches anything.

```
grep -E 'prefix.*suffix' filename
```

Comment: Sorry, not working for me... This outputs entire document.
format=HTML
prefix=`https://www.facebook.com/`
sufix=`?ref=br_rs`
any idea?

Comment: grep outputs the whole line. There are other switches to adjust that behaviour. You might want to look into an HTML parser.